# Barcode- and Character Recognition component for .Net

Tags: .net, ocr, barcode

I need to extract and decode barcodes and text from images. Is there any open source library available that helps to accomplish that task? If not, do you know a good commercial product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft.

DotImage + the [Barcode Reader addon](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/barcode/) from Atalasoft offers a Runtime Royalty-Free option that does not use any COM.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the commercial versions of both Leadtools and Atalasoft.  [Leadtools 14 sucked hardcore](http://blogs.freshlogicstudios.com/Search.aspx?q=Leadtools), I'm sure they've made it better over time.  Atalasoft is a joy to work with, if you can afford it (their pricing and licensing terms I've found to be very reasonable).

For OCR you could try one of the .NET wrappers for Google's Tesseract engine... like [Tessnet2](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/)

I would love to find a .NET open source barcode reader.

Comment: Yes, I have worked with atalasoft toolkit, its real easy to read 1D and 2D barcodes on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of Pegasus Imaging's Barcode Xpress
www.jpg.com